PDF Load Failure in Quill Project: 403 Forbidden Error on Uploadthing URL
It's a Next.js project using TypeScript, tRPC, MySQL with Prisma, and Pinecone for vector DB. Uploadthing is used for PDF uploads. When a PDF is uploaded, it uploads successfully but fails to open on the website. The browser console shows a 403 error with the URL: https://uploadthing-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${file.key}, as referenced in the Uploadthing core.ts file.
I tried to open the PDF on the website, which is a chat app designed to answer questions about the PDF for reference. This project is from a YouTuber named Josh Tried Coding. Here is the video link at timestamp 4:39:35.

The video is too long. Please provide your minimal reproducible example so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

in simple after uploading pdf it didn't open in website same error in video at time stamp 4:49:35

Check the value of the url you're passing to the file prop of the document in the PdfRenderer component.
The url should be in this format:
https://utfs.io/f/{filename}.pdf


This worked for me :
<PdfRenderer url={`https://utfs.io/f/${file.key}`} />

